# Convert Audio samples from bytes to complex numbers?

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Greetings everyone,

I am currently developing a chromatic tuner for instruments/voice in Silverlight with a C# back-end.  I am in the beginning stages and am having issues in grabbing the audio data.  I am using an AudioSink class to write the audio to a memory stream when the live capture starts.  The problem I am having is converting those bytes in the stream to complex numbers so that it can be fed into a FFT algorithm.  I have tried the various way discussed in this post [Problem to convert byte array to double](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2011214/problem-to-convert-byte-array-to-double) but am not sure which method should be used.

Any suggestions on going from a byte array to an array of complex numbers?  Accuracy and speed is a must ( more accuracy than speed ) because the later stages of my project will do this process real time in order to diplay the pitch being played as the sound is coming in.

Cheers and thanks!

Josh

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by 'convert'? For example, what is the complex equivalent of `0x78`? `7 + 8i`? Is your question really about conversion or about signal processing?

Comment: It might help if you clarified the problem for the vast majority of us not involved in singal processing. For example let's put the array to one side for the moment. Are you asking how to convert a byte to a complex number? Would it simply be the Real portion that would be set, the imaginary remaining 0?

Comment: I will probably end up asking another question on a seperate post....I too am not familiar with signal processing and am having a hard time finding where the numbers come from in some algorithms...but as this question goes, i am looking on converting. for instance a byte array that has 5 values: 115, 255, 49, 85, & 145.  Ive seen many different ways people have converted this data (which is from an audio sample). one was using BitConverter to convert the bytes to doubles...simple double cast( (double)byte[1] )...and then the method below in the first answer in this post..

Comment: then each one converts doubles to complex numbers.  I just cant find any definite explination behind the reason to use one over the other.  Thats where the problem comes in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/FftGuitarTuner.aspx) on CodeProject might be of use to you as it's in C# and deals with audio processing via the [Cooley-Turkey](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cooley%E2%80%93Tukey_FFT_algorithm) FFT algorithm.

If you don't want to sift through it here is the byte to complex number bit:
`byte[] data = yourByteArray;
double[] x = new double[data.Length];
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    x[i] = data[i] / 32768.0;
}
ComplexNumber[] data = new ComplexNumber[length];
for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
{
    data[j] = new ComplexNumber(x[i]);
}`

I don't know much about sound processing so don't know whether the dividing by 32768 is unique to this solution or true in general.

Also, although this will be 100% accurate, I don't know how well it performs.  If that becomes an issue you might need to refactor.

Comment: This method has gotten me closer to the numbers i am expecting.  Although, like you, I would like to find out where he comes up with 32768 in his algorithm :/

Comment: Did you ever find out if this is general to all complex numbers? I imagine that the 32768 is from a int16 value (256 * 128).

Answer (score 0):

Typically audio data are 16 bits with a range of -32768 to 32767 and double data has range -1 to 1.
To convert the 16bit audio data into doubles data need scales values to -1..1, that is why we divide each sample of audio data by 32768.0, which is equivalent to dividing by 2^15.