# Convert Bytes to Complex numbers

Tags: java, android, math

Is there a way to convert series of Bytes to Complexe numbers without changing the data?
for example convert  wav format files to correlate two series of bytes (2 wav files) to find the delay between them.

Comment: Those are two very different things...

Comment: You will have to be more specific. What are those bytes previously related with? Is there a particular format?

Comment: i saw this thread.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5012307/convert-audio-samples-from-bytes-to-complex-numbers. but im worried that if i do that the file data will change.

Comment: yes its a wav format. what im trying to do is to correlate two series of bytes (2 wav files) to find the delay between them.

Comment: You should really add that to your question.

Comment: Seems like a lot of information missing here.  Are you just wanting to convert the wavs into arrays of numbers representing the amplitude of each sample so you can find the point where they line up?  You'll need to know the precision of the sampling (32bit etc.) before you can convert your bytes into samples, and the original sampling frequency to find the delay in terms of time.  Additionally, if the samples are not digitally identical (recording of the same sound but by different mics, etc.) then you're also going to need to do some relatively involved preprocessing to get rid of noise etc.

Comment: i know the sampling frequency.  the first signal is generated directly into a file (without noise) the second one is the recording of file1 after a little delay. to get rid of noise i will use a filter but thats not the problem.. you said " Are you just wanting to convert the wavs into arrays of numbers representing the amplitude of each sample so you can find the point where they line up?" how is that possible? and what do you mean by "sampling precision?

Answer (score 1):

If your audio is 16bits then each byte represents half of the 16bits.Or in other words, 1 bytes contains the first 8 bits and the other 8 bits represents the other 8 bits, so what you want to do is combine (not add) the pairs of bytes to create the audio samples.Then after this make that sample the real part of the signal and set the imaginary part to 0.